Universal Linking Issue with Edge Browser in iOS App
I have managed enterprise app. universal link is working as expected from the safari but when I tried the same functionality from the managed edge browser, edge does not detect the universal link.

Unable to open our managed app from the edge browser, although from
the safari it's working as expected.
Unable to open our managed app from the outlook/Team. although from
a non-manged app, we can open our managed app.

Does edge browser support universal link?
iOS version : 17.4.1

Universal links only work in Safari
